# Как протестировать приложение на всех устройствах?

Tags: android, тестирование, экран

Здравствуйте. Написал небольшую игру, хотелось бы посмотреть, как она будет выглядеть на других устройствах, разных размеров экранах. Как мне это можно сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Comment: Спасибо, хоть что то, буду пробовать)